# What is the usage_schema object under the new tenant?

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

What is the usage_schema object under the new tenant?

I create a new tenant, and under the tenant I can query the traffic data in usage_schame, but at the same time I can create a new usage_schema database. So what is the usage_schema object under the new tenant?

```
public ❯ \c usage_schema
Cannot connect to database usage_schema.
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030017","error_message":"Database not found: \"usage_schema\""}
public ❯ select * from USAGE_SCHEMA.user_queries;
+----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| time                       | database           | host         | node_id | tenant      | user | value |
+----------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| 2023-10-09T08:57:48.882779 | asd                | 0.0.0.0:8902 | 1001    | test_tenant | root | 1     |
| 2023-10-09T08:57:58.882805 | asd                | 0.0.0.0:8902 | 1001    | test_tenant | root | 1     |
| 2023-10-09T08:58:08.883316 | asd                | 0.0.0.0:8902 | 1001    | test_tenant | root | 1     |
| 2023-10-09T08:58:18.883921 | asd                | 0.0.0.0:8902 | 1001    | test_tenant | root | 1     |
...
public ❯ create database usage_schema;
Query took 0.005 seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug that has been fixed for this issue in the latest version of cnosdb